# ListView Scrolling when Update

Tags: android, listview, chat

In a chat app the listview have 2 ways of update once when a new message pops and 
the other one load more button is Clicked

so i need 2 ways of update 
the first one is to scroll to the new message

Second is to stay at the position that clicked from

the list view have these attributes

```
  <ListView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:transcriptMode="normal" >
        </ListView>
```

the first condition is working fine 
so i need to keep the position when clicking on LoadMore

```
    public void updateWithOutScroll() {

    final int position = chListView.getSelectedItemPosition();
    Parcelable state = chListView.onSaveInstanceState();

    ChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    chListView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    chListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            chListView.setSelection(position);
        }
    });
}
```

this is Making the list to scroll to bottom first then to top

What is the wrong in this? 
and how to achieve my Goal?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you're question. If you're asking how to add more to a listview, just call:

```
Adapter.add(...) or Adapter.addAll(...)
```

and then:

```
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The listview should then just add the new elements to the bottom.

Comment: My question was about how to save the listview state when update listview

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "save the listview state"? Is this where you are currently in the listview? Edit: Why are you losing the listview state?

Comment: When updating the list view calling loadMore  its scrolls to the end because the    android:stackFromBottom="true" 

but in this state i don't need that